# How to cover test class for apex controller?

Tags: unit-test

Having trouble creating a test class for my VF Page Controller I am trying to develop.

I have created an inbound change set in my Production, and an outbound in my Sandbox. Now I am at the step of going from 0% code coverage to at least a 75% code coverage, and not having done this before, I am having issues.

```
public class MyController {
private final Contact contact;

    public MyController() {
    contact= [SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact WHERE Id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }
    public Contact getContact() {
    return contact;
    }
    public PageReference save() {
    update contact;
    return null;
    }
    }
```

Test CLass:

```
    @istest
    public class test_mycontroller{
    testmethod static void saverecord(){
    MyController my = new MyController();
    contact c = new contact();
    c.lastname = 'test';
    insert c;
    my.getContact();
    my.save();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test class is still not complete!!

```
@istest
public class test_mycontroller{
   testmethod static void saverecord(){
      contact c = new contact();
      c.lastname = 'test';
      insert c;
      PageReference myVfPage = Page.***CHANGEWITHYOURVFPAGENMAE***;
      Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);
      ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', c.Id);
      MyController my = new MyController();
      my.getContact();
      my.save();
   }
}
```

Comment: You must use System.assert , Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() in your test class. Or else it will not pass the security review.

Comment: @blackPerlSAF, your comment is more about referring to [Santanu Halder]'s answer.

Comment: yea the format he used is actually  good but i told about this because this security review issue.  And Writing test class is not just for code coverage, it has main role in testing so assert must be there. @RahulSharma.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal test class should first create the data required for the test scenario, then call the methods/constructors of the class and then assert the returned values.

```
@istest
    public class test_mycontroller{
      testmethod static void testMethodMyController(){
       //Creating the required data.
       contact c = new contact();
       c.lastname = 'test';
       insert c;
       //starting the test
       Test.startTest();
       PageReference pageRef = Page.YourVFPageName;//Observe how we set the Page here
       Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
       ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', c.Id); //see how the contact Id is set to the page params.
       MyController my = new MyController();

       Contact pageContact = my.getContact();
       System.assertEquals(pageContact.lastName, 'test'); //This should match
       my.pageContact.lastName = 'update last name';  //Update the contact's last name.
       my.save(); //the updated name should be saved now.
       System.assertEquals(my.contact.lastName, 'update last name'); //Match with the updated name
       Test.stopTest();
    }
 }
```

And you should make your contact variable in your class as `@TestVisible` so that you can test its values in the test class.